# Почему нет подсказок vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Например есть такой код, и при написании `this.$el.` нет никаких подсказок, как можно их включить в этом случае?

```js
export class test {
  constructor(selector, options) {
    this.$el = document.querySelector(selector)
    this.components = options.components || []
  }

  render() {
    this.$el.append()
  }
}
```

Comment: Какой это язык? Добавьте в теги

Answer (score 1):

Нужно проверить настройки  в файле settings.json, как описано здесь  [«Настройки пользователя и рабочей области»](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

Подсказки включаются так: `{ "editor.quickSuggestions": true }`

или так

```
// Controls if quick suggestions should show up while typing
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
},
```

Comment: Я их прописал явно в setting.json, но проблема осталась..

Comment: Может быть две ситуации подсказок нет совсем. Удали settings.json перезапусти VSCode чтоб он сбросил настройки.

Comment: или может он не работает с абстракциями?

Comment: Ситуация №2 это IntelliSense для конкретных классов не даёт подсказки. Виноват линтер который не видит объекты в синтаксическом дереве.

Comment: Дело не в абстракциях VSCode сканирует все файлы проекта если видит описания объекта на основании описания подсказывает.

Comment: Добавь в settings.json `{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}` Это говорит VSCode обрабатывать все файлы JS в рабочей области (даже неоткрытые) как часть одного проекта.

Comment: Если я указываю явно через `const app = document.querySelector('#myapp')` , в этом случае все показывается. А вот в отдельном файле компонента, где указываю в общем случае, таких подсказок нет. Правда не знаю в чем проблема. Попробывал убрать ненужные расширения и setting обнулить, не помогло. Он точно может автодополнять в файлах где нет явного присвоения elementa?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.